# Need help with a double integral in a triangular region

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to learn some maths in my own time. I am 13 and trying to learn some more maths on my own.

Can someone help me with question? My teacher could not :(

$\iint_{D}-sin(y+x) dx dy$

Where D is the triangle with vertices (0,0), (1,2) and (2,1).

From where I read online it says I should draw a triangle, but I don;tt know how this helps me...

Comment: The first thing is to identify how you integrate over the region given. Sketching will help you to understand how you should set up your integral, its bounds and whether it is easier to integrate first wrt $x$ or wrt $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to establish the boundaries of D, ie the equations of the three lines that make up the triangle.

The line $L_1$ through (0,0) and (1,2) has equation y = 2x.

The line $L_2$ through (0,0) and (2,1) has equation y = x/2.

The line $L_3$ through (1,2) and (2,1) has equation y = -x + 3.

If you sketch these on a diagram, it becomes clear that we need to consider all x between 0 and 2, and for each x we consider, we need to consider points above $L_2$. For $x\le 1$ we need to ensure the point is below $L_1$ and for $x> 1$ we need to ensure the point is below $L_3$.

This leads us to break up the integral into two parts with limits as follows:

$\int^1_{0} \int_{x/2}^{2x}-sin(y+x) dy dx +\int^2_{1} \int_{x/2}^{3-x}-sin(y+x) dy dx$

Note that I have switched dy and dx so that y becomes the "inner" variable.

To finish the question, the integral is now:

$\int^1_{0} [cos(y+x)]_{y=x/2}^{2x} dx +\int^2_{1}[cos(y+x)]_{y=x/2}^{3-x} dx$

$=\int^1_{0} cos(3x)-cos(3x/2) dx +\int^2_{1}cos(3)-cos(3x/2) dx$

$=\left [ \frac{\sin(3x)}{3}-\frac{2\sin(3x/2)}{3} \right ]_0^1 + \left [ x \cos(3)-\frac{2\sin(3x/2)}{3} \right ]_1^2 $

$=\frac13\sin(3) + \cos(3)$

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to draw the rectangle $0\leq x,y\leq2$.  This is dissected into four triangles.  It's easy to integrate over the rectangle and also over each of the three right triangles, and subtraction gives the integral over the triangle you want.